# Win32 Console Chess Black pawn font issue

Tags: c++, c, windows, fonts, console

I'm creating a simple Windows console chess interface but faced into something strange with the Black Pawn (\u265F).

With `MS Gothic` it looks like other symbols except the black pawn take single spaces:

[image]

Here is my code. Am I doing something wrong or is there a way of preventing it?

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <conio.h>

void writeConsole(HANDLE handle, const wchar_t* text)
{
    DWORD n;
    WriteConsoleW(handle, text, wcslen(text), &n, NULL);
}

int main()
{
    HANDLE handle = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX org = { 0 };
    CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX cfi = { 0 };
    cfi.cbSize = sizeof(cfi);
    GetCurrentConsoleFontEx(handle, 0, &cfi);
    memcpy(&org, &cfi, sizeof(cfi));

    wcscpy_s(cfi.FaceName, LF_FACESIZE, L"MS Gothic");
    cfi.dwFontSize.X = 50;
    cfi.dwFontSize.Y = 50;

    SetCurrentConsoleFontEx(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), FALSE, &cfi);
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(handle, BACKGROUND_INTENSITY);

    writeConsole(handle, L"White King   : \u2654\u2654\u2654\u2654           \n");
    writeConsole(handle, L"White Queen  : \u2655\u2655\u2655\u2655           \n");
    writeConsole(handle, L"White Rook   : \u2656\u2656\u2656\u2656           \n");
    writeConsole(handle, L"White Bishop : \u2657\u2657\u2657\u2657           \n");
    writeConsole(handle, L"White Knight : \u2658\u2658\u2658\u2658           \n");
    writeConsole(handle, L"White Pawn   : \u2659\u2659\u2659\u2659           \n");

    writeConsole(handle, L"Black King   : \u265A\u265A\u265A\u265A           \n");
    writeConsole(handle, L"Black Queen  : \u265B\u265B\u265B\u265B           \n");
    writeConsole(handle, L"Black Rook   : \u265C\u265C\u265C\u265C           \n");
    writeConsole(handle, L"Black Bishop : \u265D\u265D\u265D\u265D           \n");
    writeConsole(handle, L"Black Knight : \u265E\u265E\u265E\u265E           \n");
    writeConsole(handle, L"Black Pawn   : \u265F\u265F\u265F\u265F           \n");

    writeConsole(handle, L"Press any key to exit.          \n");
    _getch();

    SetCurrentConsoleFontEx(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), FALSE, &org);
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid fonts are what they are and that there is not much you can do. I tried different fonts and in all of them the black pawn is bigger than the white pawn. OTOH with the font used on this site, they have the same size: ♟♙. Anyway, copy the two pawns from this comment to Notepad and you'll see that the black pawn is buch bigger than the white one, at least with the fonts I tried.

Comment: In the MS Gothic font , U+265F has the same width as the other chess pieces.

Comment: @PeterConstable, I have tried with 'MS Gothic' and 'NSimSun' the black pawn,  U+265F,   looks different than the other characters in the console.

Comment: That may be an issue with the console; I'm pretty sure it's not an issue in the font.

Comment: @PeterConstable it looks like an issue with the font (actually with most fonts). Read my first comment.

Comment: @Jabberwocky, I think the problem with the different size pawns happens because `Segoe UI Emoji` contains a black pawn but no other chess pieces. The rest of them are pulled from `Segoe UI Symbol`. Segoe UI Symbol contains all the correct pieces but you cannot force the console to use it, unfortunately.

Comment: @PeterConstable, can you please add the other chess pieces to `Segoe UI Emoji` or remove the black pawn ;-)

Comment: @jdt but the problem is similar with Notepad and MS Word, see my first comment.

Comment: @Jabberwocky, Windows will fall back to a different font if the character that it needs to display does not exist in the current font. I would guess that in notepad and word, the black pawn is pulled from `Segoe UI Emoji` and the rest from `Segoe UI Symbol`. Most likely the system just uses the first font it finds alphabetically if it's not sure. 

Try to paste the following into word `♔♕♖♗♘♙♚♛♜♝♞♟︎` and change the font to `Segoe UI` vs `Segoe UI Emoji`.

Comment: @jdt that makes sense. Thanks

Comment: @jdt: The emoji in Segoe UI Emoji are determined by Unicode. It's not possible to add other characters as emoji that are not considered emoji in Unicode. And removing the pawn would make coverage of emoji in Segoe UI Emoji incomplete.

Comment: @jabberwocky: As jdt explained, if in (e.g.) Notepad you have selected a font that doesn't support those characters, it will select a fallback font. Windows isn't "just using the first font it finds alphabetically"; there is a specific logic and set of fonts that will be used. (Actually, slightly different in GDI than in DWrite.) But for emoji characters, preference is given to Segoe UI Emoji. However, in Notepad, if you pick a font that supports those characters, then no font fallback will occur.